# Excel VBA script

Tags: c#, excel, vba, button

I have an excel sheet which uses vba and runs some codes behind some buttons. It also involves some c# code in it (I don't know how exactly. I am not a fan of excel/vba/c# combined :) ). Anyway I can't see what is the actual code behind a particular button (e.g when I double click a button it shows the vba section but there is no code). The only think that I can see on that button is the formula: 
[image]

I want to recreate the excel interface and I want to call the same button but from another button. It may sound a bit silly but I don't know any other way of doing so. Can anyone advise on this please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a .NET control in your code.

In VBA project, check in corresponding worksheet for `_ActiveXWrapper1_...` events.

Comment: Sorry got it but still it's empty. There is definitely C# code implemented in the excel file. I can see the .cs files before running the installation of the current excel sheet.

Comment: As @GµårÐïåñ told, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>11</kbd> to open VBA IDE and them double click in something like 'Sheet1 (Sheet1)' or whatever name your worksheet has.

Comment: As it seems to create the particular excel file they have used the .Net/C# environment, something like VSTO projects (I think). So I guess there is no way to use a form button in VBA of the same excel sheet that calls the particular button that runs the code is there?

Comment: I can't reproduce your example, but your button should be exposed in VBA. Setting a appropriate type variable to object should allow you to access object members. Without a sample, I can't go much further.

Comment: Ok lets say that the C# button is called _ActiveXWrapper1 (like the example above). How can I use a button in VBA to call it?

Comment: I never had such a example. Events written in another language are maybe not accessible at all.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> will reveal the code window where you can explore the code. As for what code (aka function or module) the button is executing you can see that in the button's property or by checking the code window as well. If you paste the code, I can debug more for you.

Comment: The strange thing here is that there is no code showing behind the button.

Comment: The button will always to execute some code within the code sheet, where you can get to by using the keyboard shortcut I gave you. In some cases, it will initiate some COM or external application library but its rare for it to happen directly. So I would be very surprised to see the code page empty completely. Is there any way you can upload the actual excel file so I can rip into it and find out what you need?

Comment: I can't do that because the file is not mine.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I guess the only thing we can do is just try and give you anecdotal support on what you need to do and hope you can make it work for you.